# How does mediaelement.js work in WordPress?

Tags: theme-development, video-player

Is it automatically loaded for newly developed themes? Or should I enqueue it?

I'm developing a theme and video player doesn't seem to be working properly. Should mediaelement.js be included in footer.php or header.php in order to make the [video] shortcode work in template?

Comment: Can please clarify "*doesn't seem to be working properly*"? Does the `[video]` shortcode work in a default theme? Have you disabled all plugins? Are there errors in the JS console? How exactly are you calling the `[video]` shortcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress core handles the enqueuing of the MediaElement.js scripts and styles automatically when the `[video]` shortcode is used:

*From [`wp_video_shortcode()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/37318fe73f1b32fae1c289738f6d8cc21c99c4f8/wp-includes/media.php#L2426)...*

```
/**
 * Filters the media library used for the video shortcode.
 *
 * @since 3.6.0
 *
 * @param string $library Media library used for the video shortcode.
 */
$library = apply_filters( 'wp_video_shortcode_library', 'mediaelement' );
if ( 'mediaelement' === $library && did_action( 'init' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
}
```

The code above shows that the MediaElement.js JavaScript is added to the header, since that's how things are handled by `wp_enqueue_script()` by default.